# Почему команда "php" просто распечатывает содержимое файла, а не запускает его на выполнение?

Tags: php, debian

На сервере (продакшен Centos) файл по крону нормально запускается командой

```
php /home/bitrix/ext_www/file.php
```

а у  меня на локальном (Debian) с той же командой просто в консоли распечатывает его содержимое.

Как запустить файл на исполнение? Может, где-то в конфиге что-то прописать?

Содержимое файла:

```
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
define("NO_KEEP_STATISTIC", true);
define("NOT_CHECK_PERMISSIONS", true);
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
/*
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
/* */
//set_time_limit(50);
$obmen = new obmenOrders();
//pre($obmen);
$arOrders = $obmen->runObmenOrdersOut();

unset($obmen);
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/epilog_after.php");
```

Comment: покажите содержимое файла

Comment: Потому что забыли указать индикатор начала php-кода `<?php`

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо! Странно, на сервере работает

Comment: [Files MUST use only <?php and <?= tags.](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/). если кем-то это требование стандарта нарушается — это проблемы того, кто нарушает.

Comment: программа php версии 5.4 из официального репозитория дистрибутива centos версии 7.6 ведёт себя, кстати, точно в соответствии с указанным требованием стандарта: просто выводит в stdout содержимое приведённого вами файла.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Спасибо. Жаль, не могу плюсануть:)